# Understanding Java program execution

Tags: java

I am executing stanford nlp package to get the sentiment result.

This is the command:

```
java -cp "*" -mx5g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline -stdin
```

It reads from user and gives result when enter pressed. 
Here it shows how does it is processed:

```
H:\Drive E\Stanford\stanfor-corenlp-full-2013~>java -cp "*" -mx1g edu.stanford.n
lp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline -stdin
Adding annotator tokenize
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding annotator parse
Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCF
G.ser.gz ... done [4.7 sec].
Adding annotator sentiment
Reading in text from stdin.
Please enter one sentence per line.
Processing will end when EOF is reached.
this my first test for the. so I need to get the answer of new e. Any idea for this?
  Negative
Again we are working on new test the insert value is the test of new creation
  Neutral
```

`Negative` and `positive` is the result appear when user press enter.

My problem:

1. How can I know that which file is processed when above command is executed. I want to modify that file. Directory in which this command is executed contains some `jar` files.
2. I want to test example with new line character. Right now it stops reading from user when enter is pressed. How can I pass text as a argument which contains new line characters also.

Here is the link to source. In extract directory of this zip file the command was executed:

[http://search.maven.org/#browse|304725227](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C304725227)

Comment: Your main method is on edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline Class which Uses StanfordCoreNLP.process(String) method, you have to unzip the code and learn about how the code works.

Comment: If it's an executable, you won't be able to open it. At least not without a decompiler which isn't a 1:1 of the source. You would need at the least a `.java`